# Problem refreshing Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to refresh the current tab using my chrome extension. Why isn't the following working?

```
        var url = window.location.href;
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab{ 
        var id=tab.id
        })) 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.update(id, {url: url});
    });
```

Comment: semi colon on line 3 ? I don't know if that is really a case, but just noted that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I would combine these two functions into one. In the first call to `chrome.tabs.getSelected` you missplaced some parentheses: `function(tab{` Because there is a `)` missing there, you have two `)` at the end instead of one.

```
var url = window.location.href;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do instead, no need for window.location.href:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url});
})
```